# Rendering error when setting font-family on text-view

Tags: android

New to android programming, so please bear with me.

When I set the fontFamily on a textView in an activty, i get a "Render error" - Failed to instantiate one or more classes.

---

The following classes could not be instatiated:
    - android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (...)

Why is this happening? What Am I doing wrong?

I tried to create an empty activity, without any action bar so I used something called AppCompat. (Dont know what that is) but examples on internet told me to use that

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/main_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

I set the them in Manifest under application:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MainTheme" />
```

The class file is empty, except for the auto-generated code.

In the layout file i add a textView and set the fontFamily to anything else than empty. For example. "sans-serif". (before I set the fontFamily there is non render error).

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="net.phonefly.game.TestActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="190dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My dependencies:

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //For bottom navigation bar:
    //End of bottom navigation bar.


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app gradle just change the library version and use something lower than 26+ like below:

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

Comment: I get an error "this support library should not use a different version (25) than the compileSdkVersion(26).

Comment: you have to just change your compile version and it may be same as library version.

Comment: It seems to work now, I changed both "compileSdkVersion" and "targetSdkVersion" to 25. Is that correct? I wonder why I had to do this? Did I choose older versions of some libraries now? Why does not the 26th version work?? Thank you!

Comment: great.! i think it may be depend on library dependency and some platform tools are missing there for it can not support the some higher version library. if it there then it is ok and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You should reference your font like this @font/sans-serif

```
android:fontFamily="@font/sans-serif"
```

Comment: `@font/sans-serif`  there is no property like this

Comment: Then your font is missing. To use custom fonts you need to add them to the font resources.

Comment: I changed the font using the design-mode where I selected the font from a drop-down. I did not edit it by hand. Should I change the value of the tag?

Comment: The dropdown offers invalid options too. You can learn how to use the fonts properly at this link https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html

Comment: I tried this and it did not work for me. Thanks for the link, I will study it.

Answer (score 1):

in your project level build.gradle file check repository contains new google's maven like below

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that I also have this part.  So this is alreade taken care of.